# Can't open second form

Tags: c#

I can't open the second form I made by clicking a button.

The second Form is in the namespace MoonFTP and it has the name Form2.
I open the first Form (Form1) and want to press a button to open Form2.
But If I write this :

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MoonFTP.Form2.Show;
}
```

I get this Error :

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 4):

```
MoonFTP.Form2 form2 = new MoonFTP.Form2();
form2.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the method with params for starters.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new instance of Form2 and show that instance

```
MoonFTP.Form2 f = new MoonFTP.Form2();
f.Show();
```

You can't call directly the Show() method on the class name, you need an instance of that form.
This is possible in VB.NET for compatibility reasons, but not in C#